# In cypress, is there a way to check for a certain number of identical text or link instances?

Tags: cypress

For example, after some actions, I want to make sure 'foo' appears just and only once, or twice e.g. I can determine the complete absence of 'foo', but checking for the number of instances escapes me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the text is inside a li element and you want to make sure the number of appearances of 'foo' is more than one. One solution could be:

```
cy.get('li').invoke('text')
  .then(($text) => {
    let count = ($text.match(/foo/g) || []).length;
    expect(count).to.be.at.least(1);
    // Or you could use:
    // cy.wrap(count).should('be.at.least', 1);
  })
```

Comment: Worked great, extremely useful. Just had to tweak it with `expect(count).to.eql(1)` for my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I found this for a more simple scenario:

```
cy.get('li').filter(':contains("Services")').should('have.length', 2)
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/filter#Contains

Answer (score -1):

When you query the DOM for elements, you are getting back an array of elements found at that moment in time.
This is the case whether you intentionally expect an array or not.
The result of this query can be 0, 1 or many elements.

So if you then validate the length of this array, you will get the number of instances back.

```
cy.contains('foo').should('have.length',1);
```

will ensure that you are only getting back 1 instance of the element located by your locator strategy.

Comment: I'm getting 
"cy.contains() cannot be passed a length option because it will only ever return 1 element"